# Creating webViews programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I want to create something like an image gallery in my ViewController. For this, I'd need multiple webViews, depending on the number of images that I get from a JSON request. How can I insert new webViews if I need to?

[image]

As you can see in the above image, I have a scrollView and one UIWebView inside of the ViewController. How would I create a new webView inside of the first(second, third, etc.) if necessary? Is it possible?

Comment: You mean Image Gallery? Why to use UIWebView? there is UIImageView, and to create multiple UIImageView, you have cells, to present cells, you have UICollectionView. And for how to do that [here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=image%20gallery%20uicollectionview) is the list of tutorials. Cheers.

Answer (score 24):

you can create the web view programatically as simple as possible use this piece of code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.co.in")))
    webV.delegate = self;
    self.view.addSubview(webV)
}
```

and if you want use this delegate function

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("Webview fail with error \(error)");
}
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -&gt; Bool {
    return true;
}
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
    print("Webview started Loading")
}
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
    print("Webview did finish load")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I put it into scrollView? I have a new ViewController and it embed to the mainController. Inside of the subController I have the scrollView and I want to put this webView inside of it

Comment: ya u can use it inside scroll view as sub component

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was about to post a question, but I'm glad I found this answer....exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Less verbose: `UIWebView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)` instead of `UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)`

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webV    = UIWebView()
    webV.frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://www.apple.com")! as URL) as URLRequest)
    webV.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(webV)
}
```

Reference: Based on the answer provided by @Deepakraj Murugesan

Answer (score 2):

Although UIWebView is probably not the thing you should use for displaying images, you can create one with just a few lines of code:

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: someFrame)
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: someURL!))
view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that, Originally，webview will take up a lot of memory, if you use some quantity of it, can lead to a bad experience， why do not use ImageView？

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4:

```
webView = WKWebView()
webView.navigationDelegate = self
view = webView

let url = URL(string: "https://www.earthhero.org")!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

Plus you need to import WebKit and add WKNavigationDelegate to the Class.