# Open QR link in another ViewController in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, qr-code

I'm trying to make a QR application but I do not get the last step to work.

Today, when I do a scan, I get an alert with the result. I want that link to be sent directly to my webview controller and read the address in my webView instead of showing an alert.

**ViewController.swift**

```
func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult result: QRCodeReaderResult) {
    reader.stopScanning()



    dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
      let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Hittade",
        message: String (format:"%@", result.value, result.metadataType),
        preferredStyle: .alert


      )


      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

      self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```

**webview.swift**

```
 @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView? = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  let myURL = URL(string: "MY RESULT URL HERE")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        _ = webView?.load(myRequest)



    }
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for the help @sharon!

I have done this so far.
However, there are some error messages

See linked pictures below

[webview.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odqeS.png)

[ViewController.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVPJw.png)

**ViewController.swift**

```
 func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didScanResult result: QRCodeReaderResult) {
    reader.stopScanning()



    dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
      let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Hittade",
        message: String (format:"%@", result.value, result.metadataType),
        preferredStyle: .alert

      )
        var qrLink: String?
        qrLink = "\(result.value)\(result.metadataType)"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "WebView", sender: self)

      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

      self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "WebView" {
            let webView = segue.destination as! webview
            webView.qrLink = "%@"
        }}

  func reader(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController, didSwitchCamera newCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDeviceInput) {
    if let cameraName = newCaptureDevice.device.localizedName {
      print("Switching capturing to: \(cameraName)")
    }
  }

  func readerDidCancel(_ reader: QRCodeReaderViewController) {
    reader.stopScanning()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

**webview.swift**

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebView: UIViewController, QRCodeReaderViewControllerDelegate {




    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView? = nil
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 109/255, green: 167/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1)

        var qrLink: String?
        var webView: UIWebView?


            super.viewDidLoad()
            let myURL = URL(string: qrLink!)
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
            webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:
                UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:
                UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
            webView?.loadRequest(myRequest)
            view.addSubview(webView!)




        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first take a look at this answer to add your webView to the view programmatically (I think it's best practice to pull one from the object library in the storyboard):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651004/4301118

A simple tutorial that might help:
https://medium.com/@felicity.johnson.mail/web-view-tutorial-swift-3-0-4a5f4f6858d3

Next in your storyboard, pull a UIViewController and link it to the webview.swift class (in case you haven't done it already).

Control-drag from the ViewController to the new one you just pulled and name the segue anything you like (I'll refer it as "webview").
Create a property `var qrLink: String?`
qrLink will use to store the reader result.
Now in the reader function at ViewController.swift place the result in the qrLink you just added and trigger the segue by adding those lines:

```
qrLink = "\(result.value)\(result.metadataType)"
performSegue(withIdentifier: "webview", sender: self)
```

Declare a property to store the QR link in your webview as you did in the ViewController.

Next, add this function also in ViewController.swift:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if segue.identifier == "webview" {
        let webView = segue.destination as! webview
        webView.qrLink = "YOUR READER RESULT"
}}
```

webview.swift

```
var qrLink: String?
var webView: UIWebView?

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myURL = URL(string: qrLink!)
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
        UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 
        UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    webView?.loadRequest(myRequest)
    view.addSubview(webView!)
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: That sounds reasonable! :-)
How do I do this easiest to get started? (I'm a big beginner at swift)

Comment: See my answer above
(Trying to answer but it's above your post)