# Trigger In-App-Browser after tapping on Annotation with PDFKit - iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, pdfkit

I´m working on an app with Apple's PDFKit and have managed to put some Annotation-Buttons with a working `PDFActionURL`, which open the iOS standard browser after tapping on them.

Unfortunately, I did not find a working solution, how to open the associated links in an In-App-Browser or to load it in a webview. After tapping the AnnotationButton PDFKit automatically opens Safari and I haven´t found a property or another way concerning iOS to influence this behavior by manipulating f.e. the PDFAction.

```
let urlString = "https://www.apple.com"
let urlAction = PDFActionURL(url: urlString)
urlButton.action = urlAction
pdfPage.addAnnotation(urlButton)
```

Is there a way to force the call of an In-App-Browser at every `UIApplication.shared.open()` or to manipulate the execution of a `PDFAction`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out for myself ;) I´ve overlooked one function of the [PDFViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfviewdelegate)

By setting the delegate of the pdfView to the involved ViewController and using this function

```
func pdfViewWillClick(onLink sender: PDFView, with url: URL) {
        print(url)
}
```

you are able to use the associated URL of the PDFActionButton and to trigger an In-App-Browser (e.g. SFViewController).

Comment: This fixed an issue I was having after upgrading to iOS 13.

Comment: I'm using this delegate function but when I click on any hyperlink this function is never called. Any Idea what might be the issue?I have set the required delegate to pdfview.

Comment: I couldn't implement this solution, can you please shade a sample code? Sorry I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to resolve a similar issue. I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You want to instantiate the view like so:

```
let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.co.in")))
webV.delegate = self;
self.view.addSubview(webV)
```

> Found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651004/9333764)

To do it right, I would create a new `ViewController` in your storyboard, nested in a `navigationController` and segue to the view on annotation selection. Display your content on `viewDidLoad` using a similar set of code as seen above. That code is probably in an older version of swift so you'll need to update it. There is more detail about using the `delegate` associated in the link provided.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question. Currently I´m not able to influence the loading of the URLRequest which is associated with the PDFUrlAction. After clicking the Annotation (it´s a PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.button) the app automatically triggers the safari app and there´s no straight way of editing this behavior while setting up those Annotationbuttons. But thanks for your answer.