# "Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'PDFAction?'" error when setting an action for a PDFAnnotation

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit

In my PDF Viewer app, I successfully opened a PDF and displayed all of its content. The PDF the app will always display is quite large with 130 pages. In the second page of the PDF, there is a table of contents. I want to add a `PDFButton` to the text and scroll to the correct page in the PDF the user has selected.

My current code displays a button, but the action I want the button to perform results in an error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'PDFAction?'

Here is the code I have tried:

```
func insertResetButtonInto(_ page: PDFPage, GoTo: PDFPage) {
    let resetButtonBounds = CGRect(x: 90, y: 200, width: 200, height: 15)
    let resetButton = PDFAnnotation(bounds: resetButtonBounds, forType: PDFAnnotationSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationSubtype.widget.rawValue), withProperties: nil)
    resetButton.widgetFieldType = PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype(rawValue: PDFAnnotationWidgetSubtype.button.rawValue)
    resetButton.widgetControlType = .pushButtonControl
    resetButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    page.addAnnotation(resetButton)

    // Create PDFActionResetForm action to clear form fields.
    resetButton.action = pdfView.go(to: page)
}
```

How can I create a button in the PDF that works as a sequence or a scrolling function that takes the user to a different page in the same PDF document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a function to a variable which expects a `PDFAction`. Replace the line that throws the error with the following:

```
resetButton.action = PDFActionGoTo(destination: PDFDestination(page: page, at: .zero))
```

This passes a `PDFDestination` with the page you've initialized earlier to the  `PDFActionGoTo(destination:)` initializer.

If you want to modify the point of the destination, change the `at` parameter of the `PDFDestination` initializer to another `CGPoint` value:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)
resetButton.action = PDFActionGoTo(destination: PDFDestination(page: page, at: point))
```

Comment: I know this is a separate question, but do you know of how I can have a PDFButton segue to a different ViewController in the app? or can this not be done by a PDFButton?

Comment: @voodoo Check out this question for a delegate method that lets you run a custom function when tapping on a `PDFAnnotation`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49034120/3151675

Comment: How can I have set the Destination point to the top of the page?

Comment: @voodoo Set the `at` value to `.zero`.