# Web View crashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello and thanks for reading this, 
I'm building a simple app with 2-3 tabs (view controllers), and the first one is some kind of converter (miles to km), it's fine, and the second viewcontroller has to have a "webview" element.
So, when I build a separate app with only ONE view controller, (with "import WebKit") it works fine:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
```

BUT when I copy this to my 2-tabbed app code under the line @super.viewDidLoad()@, it crashes saying "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". 
I'm really new with this all, so I don't know how to fix this. And I didn't find solutions to similar problem on this forum. Thank you in advance!

p.s. how am I creating web view - visually add it. I see the tip to create it by coding, I will try, thank you

p.p.s. Im adding here my code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import WebKit


extension String {
func toDouble() -> Double? {
return NumberFormatter().number(from: self)?.doubleValue
} }

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var mileField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var mileResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var meters: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cmeters: UILabel!

@IBAction func mileButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let mile: Double = mileField.text?.toDouble() ?? 0
    let km = mile * 1.6
    let m = km * 1000
    let cm = m * 100
    meters.text = String(m)+" m"
    mileResult.text = String(km)+" km"
    cmeters.text = String(cm)+" cm"
}
@IBOutlet var vw: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
    vw.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "google.com")!)) // this is where I got Fatal error blah blah blah
  }
    @IBAction func bTapped() {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
        present(vc, animated: true) // this works fine but I need to use webview element
    }
}
```

[a little screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkj8o.png)

Comment: How are you creating/configuring webview instance?

Comment: just create webView programmatically instead of  storyboard.

Comment: @SPatel I will try, thank you!

Comment: @vpoltave yes I add it visually

Comment: still not working :(( @SPatel

Comment: One value is nil, which one?  Is it `webview`? Is `webview` an IBOutlet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650816/creating-webviews-programmatically-in-swift

Comment: In which controller did you add this code? First or second or tabbar controller ? Please specify.

Comment: Also please add code of webview declaration.

Comment: @shraddha11 In list on the left I have only one viewcontroller.swift... how to add second view controller to edit code?  i'm such a dumb, I guess that's why its not working

Comment: See my answer for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your two view controllers. Also please assign this class names to your view controller in storyboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDoY6.png

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}


class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }
}
```

Comment: You helped me very much, it worked!!! Thank youuuu! I will be happy to help you if there'll be anything that I can handle

Comment: Anytime. Thanks!!